# How to duplicate WPF dataGrid row by double clicking on that row?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagridview, mouseevent

I am trying to add a new row into WPF dataGrid. When I double click on the row, I need to add the same row as a new entry. My design pattern is MVVM, can't user code behind.

Please give some hint to start this work.

Comment: React on double click: 
<DataGrid.InputBindings>
                <MouseBinding  MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"  Command="{Binding AddCollectionItemCommand}" />        
 </DataGrid.InputBindings>
In command add new item to binded collection

Answer (score 0):

How about this hint? To create a duplicate row you simply have to insert a duplicate DataObject in the collection bound to the ItemsSource of that DataGrid, in the ViewModel...